# How do I set up Symfony user authentication on a different database?

Tags: authentication, symfony4

I'm using Symfony 4 and I wanted to add an user authentication. I followed the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#security-installation) to make the user entity with the MakerBundle command. But since my website has a few unrelated apps, I want this user table to be universal and be stored in its own database. In Laravel, I can do this by defining the different db connection in the database config file and then specifying which connection to use in the migration file. But I couldn't find any documentation about it for Symfony.

How do I do this?

Update detail:

The MakerBundle command "make:user" created two files, an User Entity and a UserRepository file. The User entity has property `$id`, `$username`, `$password` and `$roles`.

I'm using phpmyadmin to manage my databases, my current app deals with model so my goal is to have a model_db for the app and a site_user database for user log in. As I add more apps to the site in the future, I would create a separate database for each while the site_user database handles the authentication across all of them.

Running the command `php bin/console make:migration`created a migration file that would add the user table to the database, but I didn't know how to modify it so that table would be added to the site_user db instead of the model_db.

```php
# migration file
final class Version20190506075410 extends AbstractMigration
{
    public function getDescription() : string
    {
        return '';
    }

    public function up(Schema $schema) : void
    {
        // this up() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
        $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() !== 'mysql', 'Migration can only be executed safely on \'mysql\'.');

        $this->addSql('CREATE TABLE user (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, username VARCHAR(180) NOT NULL, roles JSON NOT NULL, password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_8D93D649F85E0677 (username), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB');
    }

    public function down(Schema $schema) : void
    {
        // this down() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
        $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() !== 'mysql', 'Migration can only be executed safely on \'mysql\'.');

        $this->addSql('DROP TABLE user');
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't told us any details of your setup. Are you truly using a separate database, or just a different schema within a common database instance? If the latter option then this is very easy to implement. Show your User entity, specifically your table name definition, so we can help you more.

Comment: Hi, I updated the details

Comment: You can definitely use multiple database connections in symfony (see https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html), but it's vastly easier to use a single database with multiple schema instead. I'm not sure you can do this with the MakerBundle, instead you would need to have your own User entity defined (perhaps the bundle generates one for you??) and specify the schema accordingly within that entity file with an annotation like `@ORM\Table(name="your-schema-name.user")`.